# path attribute in form tag

Tags: html, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

```
<tr>
<th colspan="1" align="right" >Certification Type:</th>               
<th colspan="1" align="left" style="width: 50px">
<form:select path="" id="certtype">
<form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
<form:option value="tech" label="TECHNICAL"/>
<form:option value="nontech" label="NON-TECHNICAL"/>
</form:select>
</th>
```

In this code i want to create a drop down list Which will select a value.
I have problem in this line-

```
<form:select path="" id="certtype">
```

what should i put in `path`?
And exactly when we use `form:select`,`form:option`, these kind of tags?

Comment: that looks like [spring mvc tags](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/), also you don't need the colspan attribute if it is a colspan of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for path="" attribute in form tag you have to specify the url on which to redirect the page

Comment: where can i find a documentation for this?